# Video is not started inside WebView in android API 25

Tags: android, html5-video, android-webview

I'm new to android and sorry in advance if my question is trivial but I was not able to find any solution for it.

I'm working on an android project and I have a `WebView` that displays a web page from the assets directory, my web page has a video element as shown below

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>video player</title>
</head>
<body> 
    <video width="400" controls autoplay loop muted>
        <source src="./assets/video/video1.webm" type="video/webm">
    </video>
</body> 
</html>
```

Below is java code from the `fragment` that is responsible of displaying web page:

```
mWebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/video1.html");
```

I also modified `AndroidManifest` by adding `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` for both activity and application.

When I test application on android TV emulator with API level 22 video start automatically and video controls are working properly, but when I test it using TV emulator with API level 25 video is not displayed only controls are shown but the video never started either from controls or automatically, only a white block is displayed.

**Edit 1**: add full HTML page, manifest configuration and java code for displaying HTML page.

Comment: type adding the `muted` control ... Chrome (like most users) doesn't like autoplay video with sound

Comment: I try to add it, but it does not solve issue still same behavior

Comment: do you have hardware acceleration on in your manifest `<application
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`>?

Comment: Yes I try to add it for both application and activity and it does not work

Comment: @Offbeatmammal thank you for your help. it seems that issue is emulator related, and when I test my application on a real device it is working fine.

Answer (score 3):

I'm answering my question for anyone who face same issue.

It seems that the issue is emulator related. Today I received my android TV box and when I test my application on it, it is working fine with no issues.