# how to show a video in the webview?

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, video-streaming

i want to show a video in the webview !
but not working, anyone can help me ?
link of frame : [click here](https://www.aparat.com/video/video/embed/videohash/UV9ad/vt/frame)

> "frame": "https://www.aparat.com/video/video/embed/videohash/UV9ad/vt/frame",

my code is :

```
    String url="https://www.aparat.com/video/video/embed/videohash/UV9ad/vt/frame";
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to play video URL inside android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20322057/how-to-play-video-url-inside-android-webview)

Comment: no i have black screen when playing do it in your android studio with my link and see result!!!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are setting the web view clients id:

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webview.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webview.loadUrl("url");
```

Comment: dude when i click play  video  playing but in black screen

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50127161/android-webview-black-screen-while-playing

Comment: do you have hardwareAccelerated in your manifest file?

Comment: yes  `  <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
String frameVideo = "<html><body>Youtube video .. <br> <iframe width=320 height=315 " +
"src= https://www.aparat.com/video/video/embed/videohash/UV9ad/vt/frame frameborder=0 allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>";
displayVideo = findViewById(R.id.webView);
displayVideo.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
return false;
}
});
WebSettings webSettings = displayVideo.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
displayVideo.loadData(frameVideo, "text/html", "utf-8");
```